# Using multiple procedures and multiple cursors in a package

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dbms-output

I have created a package with two procedures and two cursors in it, but while executing the procedure, it is executed successful, but same record executed multiple times and a buffer overflow occurred.

I also tried removing the loop from the cursor but for 1 record that will be fine and for multiple record it won't work as expected.

**EXPECTED**

*I just need to remove multiple execution of same record from the procedure where i am getting multiple execution of same record*

*for single procedure and single cursor it is working properly but for multiple cursor  and multiple procedure i am getting problem here which caused buffer overflow too where i need different record*

Is there any alternative way that I can fix the problem ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test.report AS
    PROCEDURE distribution (
        code_in   IN             user.test.code%TYPE,
        fromdate      date,
        todate          date
    );

    PROCEDURE tdvalue (
    id   IN          user.test.custid%TYPE
    );

END report;
/
```

Package Body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test.report as

----------VARIABLE DECLARATION----------------

    code_in             user.test.code%TYPE;
    custidin                user.test.custid%TYPE;
    fromdate                 DATE;
    todate                   DATE;
    diff                    number(17,2);
---------------CURSOR DECLARATION--------------


CURSOR td_data(code_in  user.test.code%TYPE,
                fromdate date,
                todate date
) IS

    ( SELECT
        test.code,
        COUNT(test.code) AS count,
        SUM(test2.Deposit_amount) AS total,
        test.currency
    FROM
        user.test2
        JOIN user.test ON test2.acid = test.acid
    WHERE
        user.test2.open_effective_date BETWEEN TO_DATE(fromdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE(todate, 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        and
        user.test.code = code_in
    GROUP BY
        test.code,test.currency
    );

    td__data        td_data%rowtype;


CURSOR C_DATA(custidin   user.test.custid%TYPE)  IS   SELECT
            test.custid,
            test2.id,
            TO_DATE(test2.initial_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') - TO_DATE(test2.end_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') AS noofdays,
            round(((test2.deposit_amount *((TO_DATE(test2.initial_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy') - TO_DATE(test2.end_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy'
            )) / 365) * test4.interest_rate) / 100), 2) + test2.deposit_amount AS calculated_amount,
            SUM(test.flow_amt) + test2.deposit_amount AS system_amount
        FROM
            user.test
            JOIN user.test2 ON test3.entity_id = test2.id
        WHERE
            test.custid = custidin
        GROUP BY
            test.custid,
            test2.id;

    c__data         c_data%ROWTYPE;


PROCEDURE distribution 
(
    code_in   IN             user.test.code%TYPE,
    fromdate in date,
    todate in  date
)

AS
BEGIN
    OPEN td_data(code_in,fromdate,todate);
    loop
        FETCH td_data INTO td__data;
        dbms_output.put_line(td__data.code
                             || '             '
                             || td__data.count
                             || '                '
                             ||td__data.currency
                             ||' '
                             ||td__data.total
                             );
            end loop;                
    CLOSE td_data;
END distribution;

PROCEDURE tdvalue (
    custidin   IN          user.test.custid%TYPE
    )
AS
BEGIN   
    open c_data(custidin);
    fetch c_data into c__data;
    loop
    diff:= c__data.calculated_amount- c__data.system_amount;        
        dbms_output.put_line(c__data.custid
                             || '   '
                             || c__data.noofdays
                             || '          '
                             || c__data.end_date
                             || '               '
                             || c__data.initial_date
                             || '                 '
                             || c__data.calculated_amount
                             ||'     '
                             ||diff
                             );
    end loop;
    close c_data;
END tdvalue;
END report;
/
```

To run

```
ALTER SESSION set nls_date_format='dd-mm-yyyy';
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

EXEC REPORT.DISTRIBUTION('872328','01-02-2016','08-02-2019');
/
EXEC REPORT.tdvalue('S9292879383SS53');
```

Comment: In tdvalue procedure you only fetch record once and then loop forever with the same record in variable.
Right after the 'loop' keyword you need an exit condition, and right before 'end loop' you need to fetch next record.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer overflow - ORU-10027 - happens when the total number of bytes displayed through DBMS_OUTPUT exceeds the size of the serveroutput buffer. The default is only 20000 bytes (who knows why?). Your session is using that default because of how you enable `serveroutput`. Clearly one record is less than 2000 and you only hit that limit when you run for multiple records.

To fix this try this

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON size unlimited
```

It's not actually unlimited, but the upper bound is the PGA limit (session memory) and you really shouldn't hit that limit with DBMS_OUTPUT. Apart from anything else who would read all that?

---

So the other problem with your code - as @piezol  points out - is that your loops have no exit points. You should test whether the FETCH actually fetched anything and exit if it didn't:

```
loop
    FETCH td_data INTO td__data;
    exit when td_data%notfound; 

    dbms_output.put_line(td__data.code
                         || '             '
                         || td__data.count
                         || '                '
                         ||td__data.currency
                         ||' '
                         ||td__data.total
                         );
 end loop;
```

Remembering to do this is just one reason why implicit cursors and cursor for loops are preferred over explicit cursors.

The second cursor loop is even worse because not only does it not have an exist point, the fetch is **outside the loop**. That's why you have repeated output for the same record.

So let's rewrite this ...

```
open c_data(custidin);
fetch c_data into c__data;  -- should be inside 
loop
diff:= c__data.calculated_amount- c__data.system_amount;
```

… as a cursor for loop:

```
PROCEDURE tdvalue (
    custidin   IN          user.test.custid%TYPE
    )
AS
BEGIN   
    for c__data in c_data(custidin)
    loop
        diff:= c__data.calculated_amount- c__data.system_amount;        
        dbms_output.put_line(c__data.custid
                             || '   '
                             || c__data.noofdays
                             || '          '
                             || c__data.end_date
                             || '               '
                             || c__data.initial_date
                             || '                 '
                             || c__data.calculated_amount
                             ||'     '
                             ||diff
                             );
    end loop;
END tdvalue;
```

No need for OPEN, CLOSE or FETCH, and no need to check when the cursor is exhausted.

Comment: Buffer overflow was not really the issue with his code, it was only the result of the forever-loop.

Comment: Same record is executed multiple times and buffer overflow occurred , where i don't need execution of same record multiple time @APC

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL, the preferred mechanism for setting the `DBMS_OUTPUT` buffer size would be within your procedure. This has the benefit of working in any client tool, such as Java or Toad (though it is still up to the client tool to retrieve the output from `DBMS_OUTPUT`).

[DBMS_Output.ENABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_output.htm#TTPLP71205)

Pass in a parameter of `NULL` for unlimited buffer size.

It would go like this:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(NULL);
  FOR I IN 1..1000 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Bonus fact:

You can use the other functions and procedures in `DBMS_OUTPUT` to roll your own if you aren't using SQL*Plus or a `DBMS_OUTPUT`-savvy tool like Toad.
You can use the `GET_LINE` or `GET_LINES` procedures from your client code to get whatever may have been written to `DBMS_OUTPUT`.

[GET_LINE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTPLP/d_output.htm#TTPLP71207)

Comment: Some sites only use `dbms_output` for developer diagnostics and expect it to be disabled in production, so enabling it within the code commits you to the overhead and potential for excessive PGA use. That may never actually be a problem of course.